# C# error (on monitoring bytes received/sent) [edited]

Tags: c#

I would like to monitor the bytes that were sent and received by an RFID reader. But this thing doesn't compile. :(
It says it lacks '}' however if I put one, transportLogFile (on function SerialListener) is not recognized. 
What's wrong with this?

Copyright (c) 2009 ThingMagic, Inc.

```
   using System; // system namespace reserved for items associated with .NET Framework class library
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Data;
using System.Threading;
using ThingMagic;


namespace Read_v5
{
    class Program
    {
        private TextWriter transportLogFile;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            TextWriter transportLogFile;
            StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("log.txt");
            writer.AutoFlush = true;
            transportLogFile = writer;
            using (Reader rdr = Reader.Create("tmr:///com29"))
            {
                if (rdr is SerialReader)
                    rdr.Transport += TimestampListener;

                SimpleReadPlan readplan = new SimpleReadPlan();
                rdr.Connect(); //establish connection
                rdr.ParamSet("/reader/region/id", Reader.Region.OPEN); //region set in OPEN
                rdr.ParamSet("/reader/read/plan", readplan);
                int[] antennas = (int[])rdr.ParamGet("/reader/antenna/connectedPortList");
                rdr.ParamSet("/reader/tagop/antenna", 1);
                rdr.ParamSet("/reader/tagop/protocol", TagProtocol.GEN2);
                //   Console.WriteLine(rdr.ParamGet("/reader/tagop/antenna"));
                //   Console.WriteLine(rdr.ParamGet("/reader/tagop/protocol"));
                //  Console.WriteLine(" " + rdr.ParamGet("/reader/antenna/portList"));
                //   rdr.ParamSet("/reader/antenna/txRxMap", new int[][]{new int[]{1,1,1}});
                readplan.Antennas = new int[] { 1 };
                //    Console.WriteLine(" " + rdr.ParamGet("/reader/antenna/portList").ToString());
                readplan.Protocol = TagProtocol.GEN2;
                //      Console.WriteLine(rdr.ParamGet("/reader/antenna/portList"));
                rdr.ParamSet("/reader/read/asyncOffTime", 100);
                rdr.ParamSet("/reader/read/asyncOnTime", 500);
                rdr.StartReading();
                //     Console.WriteLine("FIN");
                //     int y = 0;
                while (rdr.Equals(rdr))
                {

                    //  Console.WriteLine("\r\n<Do this\r\n");
                    rdr.TagRead += delegate(Object sender, TagReadDataEventArgs e)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("EPC: " + e.TagReadData.EpcString);
                        Console.WriteLine("RSSI: " + e.TagReadData.Rssi.ToString());
                        Console.WriteLine("Phase: " + e.TagReadData.Phase.ToString());
                    };
                    Thread.Sleep(200);

                }
                rdr.StopReading();
                rdr.Destroy();
                transportLogFile.Close();
            }
        }
        private void TimestampListener(Object sender, TransportListenerEventArgs e)
        {
         //   TextWriter transportLogFile = null;
            transportLogFile.Write(String.Format("{0} {1}",
                DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss.fff tt"),
                e.Tx ? "Sending" : "Received"));
            for (int i = 0; i < e.Data.Length; i++)
            {
                if ((i & 15) == 0)
                {
                    transportLogFile.WriteLine();
                    transportLogFile.Write("  ");
                }
                transportLogFile.Write("  " + e.Data[i].ToString("X2"));
            }
            transportLogFile.WriteLine();
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put one more `}` at the end of the file. From where i can see the namespace is never closed.

EDIT:
Problem with the variable. You can solve this by doing as following to access it in the method.

```
class Program 
{ 
    //Declare the variable here:
    private static TextWriter transportLogFile;

    public static void Main(string[] args) 
    {
       //TextWriter transportLogFile = null; 
       transportLogFile = writer;          
    }
    private static void MyMethod()
    {
       //Access transportLogFile here.
    }
}
```

Comment: yes.I see it now. Although just like what I've mentioned, transportLogFile is still not recognized.


Error 1 The name 'transportLogFile' does not exist in the current context

Comment: You are using the variable in a method, but it's not declared in that method. You must declare the variable in the method or the class to access it. Updated my post so you can see how you can access it from the method

Comment: The compiler looks for a static Main for entry point. :(

Comment: Missed it in my example. It was just for you to get the hang of it. Updated now.

Comment: followed your advise thourhg another error encountered.

Error 1 An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Read_v5.Program.TimestampListener(object, ThingMagic.TransportListenerEventArgs)'

I forgot to put public but anyway still bears same error. :(

Comment: Mine was just a example. In this case we need to have the outside scoped variable as a static to be able to access it from Main(). Updated the exmaple.